# YUI chart legend

Tags: charts, yui, legend

I am looking for documentation on how to display legends in YUI charts. I couldn't find anything on http://yuilibrary.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the yui library has a legend option available now: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/charts/charts-legend.html

important is to use the module by starting with:

```
 YUI().use('charts-legend', function (Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The YUI 3 library does not have a built-in chart legend. See this [YUI forum discussion](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=21240) which mentions that one is planned for a future release of YUI 3.x.

There is also one [chart legend module](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/charts-legend) listed in the YUI Gallery that might meet your needs.